Define beaming within tuplet in music21
Using music21, I'm trying to create a measure with the following rhythm and beaming:

However, no matter what I try, I can't get the beaming right. Here is my attempt and the result:
import copy
import music21 as m21

m = m21.stream.Measure()
m.timeSignature = m21.meter.TimeSignature('2/4')

note_first = m21.note.Note('C4', type='eighth')
# note_first.beams.fill("eighth", "stop")
m.append(note_first)

tuplet = m21.duration.Tuplet(3, 2, "eighth")
duration = m21.duration.Duration("eighth")
duration.appendTuplet(tuplet)
note_tuplet = m21.note.Note('C4', duration=duration)
notes_tuplet = [copy.deepcopy(note_tuplet) for _ in range(3)]
notes_tuplet[0].beams.fill("eighth", type="start")
notes_tuplet[-1].beams.fill("eighth", type="stop")
for n in notes_tuplet:
    m.append(n)

note_last = m21.note.Note('C4', type='eighth')
# note_last.beams.fill("eighth", "start")
m.append(note_last)

m.show()


I tried to play with the beaming in every way I could think of, but the results always looks like this. The beaming indications I give do not seem to be taken into account.
Is there a way to achieve this?
Notes:

The m.show() uses MuseScore 4.3.1 to render the score (MuseScore is able to deal with the expected result as I made the example with it).
I do not care about the key of the number of lines in the staff, only the rhythm and beaming.

